Is the meaning of "confessing the need for XYZ" appropriate?
I have written a story about how I realized I need God.
Is it okay to title it:

"Confessing the Need for God"?

According to Cambridge Dictionary the verb confess means


to admit that you have done something wrong or something that you feel guilty about: “The man has confessed to stealing the painting.”
to tell a priest or God about all the wrong things that you have done


According to Oxford dictionary

Confess.
declare (one's religious faith).
"150 people confessed faith in Christ".

Is the usage of the word "confessing", in my title, inappropriate?

Dictionary Definitions from Oxford Languages · verb: confess ; 3rd person present: confesses; past tense: confessed; past participle: confessed; gerund or present participle: confessing declare (one's religious faith). "150 people confessed faith in Christ"

Normally one confesses a transgression, and professes their faith.  In ancient Rome during the period when Christianity was illegal, a Christian might "confess" their faith.  In situations where people are  reluctant to admit publicly to being a devout believer, "confess" is used.  There is an implication that it is a hurdle, something difficult to do.

Your title is ABSOLUTELY FINE and appropriate.

The distinction between profession of faith and confession of faith is frequently the subject of sermons and tracts about what it takes to be "true" believer (usually Protestant Christian believer). If you have no problem being identified with those opinions, then go for it. Just realize that the phrase "confessing your faith" has connotations and expectations that go well beyond the simple denotative definition "declare" that Oxford offers.

I guess downvoters to my answer looked only at the Cambridge dictionary meaning, which was only there. Cambridge dictionary doesn't describe confessing one's faith.  I added the Oxford dictionary meaning to the question.

@JamesMathai I suggest that you look carefully; the first comment included the Oxford Languages definition. People will have seen that comment, posted by a hi-rep user no less, submitted very soon after the question was posted.

confessing a/the need for x is completely idiomatic in English. That's the point here. confess here means to admit to something.

Titles like this are often figurative, so don't worry so much about the precise dictionary definitions.
Even if you don't actually feel guilty about your need for God, many readers who are not religious might believe that you should feel guilty. So from their perspective, it's appropriate that you would label this as a confession.
It also adds some emotion to the title. You could have a title like:

Explanation of the need for God

But this neutral word doesn't draw the reader in as well.

I. Testimony vs Confession.
OP has asked whether to use the word "confessing"  in his book title :

I have written a story about how I have realized I need God.

Answer:
As suggested in the Oxford dictionary your title is appropriate. You can also "confess your faith". Looking only Cambridge dictionary meanings suggest that the word "confess" can only mean "confessing your sins or guilt".
While the word  "confessing" can work, I believe "testimony" is more appropriate in this context.
If you search for  "Testimony of _" on YouTube, you’ll see many examples that align with the meaning of a personal account of religious conversion or spiritual realization. (I watch such videos)
II. Dictionary meanings:

Confession.
.a statement setting out essential religious doctrine.
.
Testimony.
a public recounting of a religious conversion or experience.

III. Title Suggestions:.
Here are a few title suggestion:

Testimony of __
How I found faith in God.
A Journey to accepting God
My spiritual awakening


It's not about the word "confession", it's abut the noun ing-form "confessing" The OP is not asking for title suggestions either, which would be off-topic. -1

@Mari-LouA This is what OP asked,  "Is This a Correct Word for a Story Title?". I find that you have edited and changed to concentrate on one word. My answer is intended to suggest different titles for his book.

@Mari-LouA Where did OP add the meanings (which doesn't work)? In my search I found a meaning which suggests  "confession or confessing" can work, which I included in my answer. When you edit a question, you are supposed to correct incorrect things. My answer was written after reading the initial post.

You can edit a post if you believe it deserves to stay open, there is one vote in favour of closing. I added the research, it says so in the edit summary. This is the link to the original post. It was very bare, I wanted to help the author. You can rollback the edits if you retain that they were harmful. I believe they are not. The edit also included removing the second present perfect "have" in: "I have written a story… have realized I need God" So the second present perfect is unnecessary, it's not wrong but the question reads better.

@Mari-LouA Then you should add a meaning which shows that the title is correct. There is not only confession of sins but also "confession of faith

to confess a/the need for something  is idiomatic in English. Period.
